# Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, tuples

I'm finishing a port for a project that was written in Swift to support Objective-C. A lot of the project was written to support Objective-C but not the properties on a particular class.

This is the property:

```
open var remainingTime: ( hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int)?
```

I'm guessing I can't just add `@objc` to this because "hours","minutes","seconds" are objects. How do I make this property visible to my Objective-C project?

Comment: There's no tuple type in Objective-C. You need to use other type (class, maybe) to make it exportable to Objective-C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a class that represents your tuple.

**Code:**

```
class Time: NSObject {
    let hours: Int
    let minutes: Int
    let seconds: Int

    init(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds
    }
}

@objc open var remainingTime: Time?
```

Comment: Better add `@objcMembers` to make a class which needs to be accessed from Objective-C code.

Comment: @OOPer: ~Not if it's a NSObject subclass which is already exposed to Objective-C~ EDIT: just seen what was meant, objcMembers makes all members exposed, not just the class :ok-hand:

Answer (score 3):

This error occurred in project when I tried to observe an Enum via KVO. My enum looked like this:

```
enum EnumName: String {
    case one = "One"
    case two = "Two"
}
```

In case you are struggling to observe it, this workaround helped solve my issue.

### Observable Class:

- create `@objc dynamic var observable: String?`
- create your enum instance like this:

  ```
  private var _enumName: EnumName? {
      didSet {
          observable = _enumName!.rawValue
      }
  }
  ```

### Observer Class:

- create `private var _enumName: EnumName?`
- create `private let _instance = ObservableClass()`
- create

  ```
  private var _enumObserver: NSKeyValueObservation = _instance.observe(\.observable, options: .new, changeHandler: { [weak self] (_, value) in
      guard let newValue = value.newValue else { return }
      self?._enumName = EnumName(rawValue: period)!
  })
  ```

Than's it. Now each time you change the `_enumName` in the observable class, an appropriate instance on the observer class will be immediately updated as well.

This is of course an oversimplified implementation, but it should give you an idea of how to observe KVO-incompatible properties.